# permissions on the view are not getting replicated

Tags: sql-server, replication

im using sql server 2012 and transactional replication in it. im trying to replicate a view which has a specific database role attached in the permissions. this is my replications script for the view

```
:setvar SubscriberDB "ReplicationSubscriberDB"
:setvar SubscriberServerName "HYDHTC0131320D\MSSQLSERVER2"
:setvar PublisherDB "PublisherDB"
:setvar PublisherServerName "HYDHTC0131320D"
:setvar ReplicationAccount "myusername"
:setvar ReplicationAccountPassword "mypassword"

GO
:on error exit
GO

exec sp_addpublication @publication = N'DepartmentsView', @description = N'Transactional publication of database from Publisher ''$(PublisherServerName)''.', @sync_method = N'concurrent', @retention = 0, @allow_push = N'true', @allow_pull = N'true', @allow_anonymous = N'false', @enabled_for_internet = N'false', @snapshot_in_defaultfolder = N'true', @compress_snapshot = N'false',  @allow_subscription_copy = N'false', @add_to_active_directory = N'false', @repl_freq = N'continuous', @status = N'active', @independent_agent = N'true', @immediate_sync = N'true', @allow_sync_tran = N'false', @autogen_sync_procs = N'false', @allow_queued_tran = N'false', @allow_dts = N'false', @replicate_ddl = 1, @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'false', @enabled_for_p2p = N'false', @enabled_for_het_sub = N'false'

GO
exec sp_addpublication_snapshot @publication = N'DepartmentsView', @frequency_type = 1, @frequency_interval = 0, @frequency_relative_interval = 0, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 0, @frequency_subday_interval = 0, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 0, @active_end_date = 0, @job_login = N'$(ReplicationAccount)', @job_password = '$(ReplicationAccountPassword)', @publisher_security_mode = 1
GO


exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'DepartmentsView', @article = N'vwDepartments', @source_owner = N'dbo', @source_object = N'vwDepartments', @type = N'view schema only', @description = null, @creation_script = null, @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x48000001, @destination_table = N'vwDepartments', @destination_owner = N'dbo'
GO

EXEC sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication = N'DepartmentsView'
GO


use [$(PublisherDB)]
GO
exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'DepartmentsView', @subscriber = N'$(SubscriberServerName)', @destination_db = N'$(SubscriberDB)', @subscription_type = N'Push', @sync_type = N'automatic', @article = N'all', @update_mode = N'read only', @subscriber_type = 0
GO

exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'DepartmentsView', @subscriber = N'$(SubscriberServerName)', @subscriber_db = N'$(SubscriberDB)', @job_login = N'$(ReplicationAccount)', @job_password = '$(ReplicationAccountPassword)', @subscriber_security_mode = 1, @frequency_type = 4, @frequency_interval = 1, @frequency_relative_interval = 0, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 8, @frequency_subday_interval = 6, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 20120607, @active_end_date = 99991231, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', @dts_package_location = N'Distributor'
GO
```

after replicating, the view is getting created but the role is not getting attached to permissions of the view. this role is present in both publisher and subscriber databases. and this roles is assigned to the table used in the view and the table exists on both the databases.

i tried setting the schema_option to 0x48000001 which is

1. Generates the object creation script (CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, and so on). This value is the default for stored procedure articles.
2. Create any schemas not already present on the subscriber.
3. Replicate permissions.

i have also gone through this post, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/a4fa2d32-00ea-47a7-9276-52764fab72ae/ which says above schema_option value should work. or we have to use @post_snapshot_script in sp_addpublication.

i tried with @post_snapshot_script and it is working, but i dont want to use this approach.

please let me know how to solve this problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: this looks like an issue in sql server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in SQL Server 2012. This issue happens because of a bug in the snapshot agent. There is a work around for now till Microsoft release a fix for this issue:
1. Open the snapshot folder.
2. Edit the .sch file for your view by adding the required permissions.

Subscribers can get the correct snapshot after that.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same known bug.  Result was to specify a permission granting script in the Run Additional Scripts - After Applying Snapshot property of the publication.