# How to make SQL Server copy permissions for view in merge replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

I have a merge replication in my SQL Server 2008.

I'm replicating some views, and I can't find an option to copy permissions for it, while tables, stored procedures and user-defined functions have this option.

I see only "Copy extended properties" option, but, as I know, this option is for view diagram.

I found ["permissions on the view are not getting replicated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235796/permissions-on-the-view-are-not-getting-replicated), but this is a SQL Server 2012 issue.

Is there any possibility to copy it, cause I don't like workaround for issue above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Copy permissions article property is not exposed via the Article Properties dialog, you must add the article to the Merge publication using [sp_addmergearticle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174329.aspx) and include **@schema_option** 0x40000000 which will copy permissions.

I've tested this in SQL Server 2008 and it works perfectly.  However, I've tested this on SQL Server 2012 and there is a bug which prevents the permissions from being copied to subscribers.  In that case, you would need to workaround the issue using a [post snapshot script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152525.aspx) or post the GRANT statements to subscribers using [sp_addscriptexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174360.aspx).